# Matplotlib a huge amount of data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to plot a huge amount of data, but when i do matplotlib does wierd things.

See:

[image: Plotted Recall Figure]

It looks like the data is not continous, but it is, it attached the two lists at the end.I read that python list are ordered so, there should be no problem ploting those.
So my question is what does cause those wierd horizontal lines?

**Note**: If I plot less values at the same time it works. (plotting about 25 values results in a better graph, here only the end and start points are falsly connected: [Plotted Recall Figure with less values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMCBa.png))

Here is a short extraction of my code:

```
superpix = superpixelNumber
results = recallAVG
plt.ylabel('Recall')
plt.xlabel('Superpixels')
print superpix
print '####'
print results
plt.plot(superpix, results)

superpix = ['964', '1091', '1536', '1629', '1810', '1901', '1964', '2018', '2088', '2349', '2417', '2469', '2654', '2765', '2848', '2892', '2941', '2974', '3064', '3081', '3115', '3119', '3143', '3150', '3155', '3212', '3289', '3318', '3377', '3405', '3407', '3516', '3533', '3547', '3810', '4012', '4013', '4053', '4209', '4285', '4316', '4424', '4431', '4475', '4478', '4499', '4560', '4564', '4619', '4830', '4837', '4849', '4875', '4881', '4975', '4995', '5024', '5071', '5209', '5273', '5288', '5339', '5352', '5371', '5539', '5617', '5792', '5821', '5851', '5859', '5896', '5906', '5971', '5992', '6063', '6137', '6150', '6159', '6168', '6259', '6282', '6324', '6348', '6402', '6501', '6522', '6593', '6647', '6662', '6681', '6824', '6835', '6840', '6869', '6879', '6933', '6949', '7086', '7132', '7156', '7175', '7184', '7211', '7248', '7368', '7472', '7489', '7500', '7511', '7655', '7747', '7779', '7915', '7935', '8050', '8165', '8222', '8262', '8264', '8438', '8443', '8545', '8557', '8644', '8671', '8710', '8779', '8786', '8830', '8851', '8909', '8957', '9008', '9030', '9044', '9045', '9178', '9385', '9466', '9539', '9568', '9580', '9589', '9603', '9730', '10040', '10182', '10285', '10345', '10539', '10542', '10623', '10674', '10736', '10841', '10907', '10928', '10952', '11096', '11140', '11157', '11260', '11316', '11501', '11529', '11568', '11668', '11700', '11749', '11902', '12079', '12236', '12330', '12585', '12804', '13274', '13459', '13602', '13944', '13998', '14157', '14553', '14854', '14857', '15202', '15271', '15930', '16014', '16791', '17242', '18739', '19349', '20145', '21340', '21503', '21848', '22385', '22934', '24635']

####

results = [0.544489, 0.6476833333333333, 0.8120071666666666, 0.6834395, 0.561904625, 0.6241478, 0.5198309999999999, 0.7997744000000001, 0.7927402, 0.38733540000000005, 0.6811011666666666, 0.31748319999999997, 0.6906548, 0.7104231999999999, 0.7904592, 0.6112666, 0.6112056000000001, 0.7106966, 0.6786711666666667, 0.7043264, 0.6531032, 0.7107464, 0.6141873333333333, 0.642922, 0.6281375, 0.6531969999999999, 0.5334163999999999, 0.713445, 0.6838645, 0.55517, 0.5588808000000001, 0.7401632, 0.7575395, 0.49618900000000005, 0.7326644999999999, 0.5333436, 0.7480956, 0.6763588, 0.6479583333333333, 0.6086701666666667, 0.6886296666666666, 0.7927191666666666, 0.7872138000000001, 0.8386618333333334, 0.6493258, 0.6309176000000001, 0.7231950000000001, 0.7305621666666667, 0.5309332, 0.6586155, 0.7128357999999999, 0.7975034000000001, 0.7444255999999999, 0.8303649999999999, 0.5679306, 0.6392124, 0.6555251666666666, 0.6552325999999999, 0.6678068, 0.7479224, 0.46856919999999996, 0.8193335, 0.7291534, 0.7705025, 0.6188564, 0.5745034, 0.8803211666666666, 0.745825, 0.7317174, 0.7680821666666667, 0.7515812, 0.7993342, 0.6954322000000001, 0.7003165, 0.6238643333333334, 0.5572301666666667, 0.7930182, 0.6068512, 0.7714650000000001, 0.7329275000000001, 0.8182447999999999, 0.6985256, 0.7509342000000001, 0.7008111999999999, 0.7911758, 0.7273213999999999, 0.7524605999999999, 0.7907938333333333, 0.7576454, 0.8556896, 0.6714838, 0.6430279999999999, 0.7651656, 0.7390004, 0.7064493333333332, 0.7085924, 0.7695102, 0.8192638333333333, 0.7551354, 0.7028121666666668, 0.875455, 0.7522068333333333, 0.7189924, 0.72603575, 0.6959801666666666, 0.7299698333333334, 0.7037495999999999, 0.7682484, 0.7910786000000001, 0.6468406, 0.7914950000000001, 0.8298270000000002, 0.5833666666666667, 0.6716734000000001, 0.693755, 0.7038998000000001, 0.7118356666666669, 0.6176462, 0.7862823999999999, 0.6589343999999999, 0.641948, 0.6550428, 0.8077074285714285, 0.7217188, 0.8171754, 0.7455430000000001, 0.6760586666666666, 0.8073192, 0.7526198000000001, 0.5985636, 0.5884878, 0.7315267999999999, 0.7921850000000001, 0.7785071666666666, 0.8030158000000001, 0.7808846, 0.8635564, 0.791552, 0.6418918, 0.5921538, 0.5714445, 0.8469682000000001, 0.7457960000000001, 0.6528014, 0.7953612, 0.7482305454545455, 0.6620106000000001, 0.6857932000000001, 0.7869412, 0.8119694999999999, 0.8080288, 0.7167660000000001, 0.7879052, 0.8158552, 0.7944292, 0.6462405999999999, 0.5717346, 0.746576, 0.7192412000000001, 0.6327026, 0.8053162, 0.8435456, 0.45326260000000007, 0.702516, 0.6550973999999999, 0.8167049999999999, 0.858953, 0.7403408, 0.8037054000000001, 0.8554501999999999, 0.7444812857142857, 0.8347054, 0.7900281999999998, 0.6243236, 0.6781092, 0.8021786000000001, 0.7439516000000002, 0.8221598, 0.6984858, 0.8066198333333334, 0.8586328, 0.8275296666666666, 0.7771527500000001, 0.7977257999999999, 0.7837116000000001, 0.8565828333333334, 0.8518712857142857, 0.8727360000000001, 0.7884179999999998, 0.8158571428571427, 0.8863956666666667, 0.7524074, 0.7211422, 0.7527022, 0.8259815999999999, 0.7555484, 0.7844934, 0.7150338, 0.8842191666666667]
```

Comment: Lists are ordered, but not sorted. 1. I find it weird that your x data are strings, I don't know how mpl handles that (try converting to ints), 2. Make sure the data are sorted (and watch out for lexicographical string sorting).

Comment: I tried plotting your data, I don't see any artifacts.

Comment: Yeah i converted it to INTs and now it works for me too! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problems with jumps in the plot using the data you included in the question. That being said, make sure you don't want to plot *with respect to integer points* instead of strings. In the former case each data point is plotted equidistantly, and labels are set according to your string x data. You may instead want to use the integer value of the strings in your x data instead.

Compare:

```
plt.plot(superpix, results)
```

[image: original: string x]

with

```
plt.plot(list(map(int,superpix)), results) # list() is superfluous on python 2
```

[image: new: plotted vs ints]